# Why do my images only load on desktop, but not mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, image, mobile

I'm creating a web application. I've included a Codepen if that's helpful, as well as a link to the live site. When I open the application on my desktop browser, the images load. When I open the site on my mobile browser, I just get sort of a gray outline of the image.

To replicate this bug, select `Alien` from the dropdown menu labeled `Shape:`, then click `"clear and apply"`. Then, click on any of the black squares. It should turn into an alien head, you'll see it work on the desktop browser, do the same process in any mobile browser, and this will not work.

Live Site: https://zjcrumpton.github.io/tokeneconomy/

Codepen: https://codepen.io/zjcrumpton/pen/rNOMZdr

```
.alienItem {
      content: url(/images/alien.png);
      height: 55px;
      width: 55px;
      justify-self: center;
      border-radius: 50px;
      margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Codepen won't have the image files included but might help you look through the code.

Comment: No image on the website either. Maybe it is cached by your desktop browser.

Comment: Oh wow that's helpful to know, yeah it seems it was cached in my browser and now I see that the live version does not have the images. They do however load when I run my server live from VS Code locally...

Comment: I don't see the `class='alienItem'` in your HTML, but maybe JavaScript is making it have that class. Anyway `content: url(/images/alien.png);` should be `background-image:url(images/alien.png);`. By the way, having large images scale down like that is generally a bad practice, since it will have to load the entire image, before the scale. It's best to have images stay the size they are.

Answer (score 0):

You are linking to the wrong place. Your website is being hosted at `https://zjcrumpton.github.io/tokeneconomy/`. The assets you are linking to are using a starting slash (`/images/alien.png`), which will be relative to the base URL, so that would resolve to `https://zjcrumpton.github.io/images/alien.png`, which does not exist.

Since your entire repository is being hosted at `https://zjcrumpton.github.io/tokeneconomy/`, you should link to `/tokeneconomy/images/alien.png` instead, or remove the starting slash, or link to `./images/alien.png`.